# Ratchet - how do I send message on click

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

Recently been learning how to implement websockets in PHP with the use of Ratchet, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with button clicks.

Here is my current JS/jQuery code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        let conn;

        $('#join-chat').on('click', function()
        {
            let userName = $('#name').val();
            conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

            $('#chat-room').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#enter-name').addClass('hidden');

            connect();

            $('#send-msg').attr('data-user', userName);
            $('.page-header h1').append(' '+ userName)
        });

        $('#disconnect').on('click', function()
        {
            $('#chat-room').addClass('hidden');
            $('#enter-name').removeClass('hidden');

            conn.close();
            alert('Bye Bye Bud')
        });

        $('#send-msg').on('click', function()
        {
            let msg = $('#msg').val();
            sendMsg(msg, conn)
        });

        function sendMsg(msg, conn)
        {
            conn.onmessage = function(e)
            {
                $('#chat-history').append(buildHtml(e))
            };

            conn.send(msg)
        }

        function buildHtml(data)
        {
            let html = '';

            html += '<div class="row">';
            html += '    <div class="col-sm-2">';
            html += '        '+ data.user +' ('+ new Date(data.timeStamp*1000) +'): ';
            html += '    </div>';
            html += '    <div class="col-sm-5">';
            html +=          data.data;
            html += '    </div>';
            html += '</div>';

            return html
        }

        function connect()
        {
            alert('welcome, to the room of chat.')
        }
    });
```

This works from the 2nd time onwards. The first time the button is pressed, nothing happens - second click (and every click thereafter) seems to work.

What's my code doing wrong?

Side question: can conn.send take in arrays? If I wanted to do:

```
var msg = {
    msg: 'user inputted msg',
    user: 'user who sent data'
}
```

and use that to get the user who sent the msg?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're defining `conn.onmessage` handler when button is pressed. Put it outside the function, or after WS connection, and it should work.
Actually message is being sent but you just don't receive it back, as there's nothing to do on new message.

For side question, you can serialize it as JSON and decode it on server side.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    let conn;

    $('#join-chat').on('click', function()
    {
        let userName = $('#name').val();
        conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
        conn.onmessage = function(e)
        {
            $('#chat-history').append(buildHtml(e))
        };
        $('#chat-room').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#enter-name').addClass('hidden');

        connect();

        $('#send-msg').attr('data-user', userName);
        $('.page-header h1').append(' '+ userName)
    });

    $('#disconnect').on('click', function()
    {
        $('#chat-room').addClass('hidden');
        $('#enter-name').removeClass('hidden');

        conn.close();
        alert('Bye Bye Bud')
    });

    $('#send-msg').on('click', function()
    {
        let msg = $('#msg').val();
        sendMsg(msg, conn)
    });

    function sendMsg(msg, conn)
    {
        conn.send(msg)
    }

    function buildHtml(data)
    {
        let html = '';

        html += '<div class="row">';
        html += '    <div class="col-sm-2">';
        html += '        '+ data.user +' ('+ new Date(data.timeStamp*1000) +'): ';
        html += '    </div>';
        html += '    <div class="col-sm-5">';
        html +=          data.data;
        html += '    </div>';
        html += '</div>';

        return html
    }

    function connect()
    {
        alert('welcome, to the room of chat.')
    }
});
```

Comment: sorry? I don't get you - yeah you get the message but there's no function to handle it. when you click send, you set a function to handle incoming message. that's why you see the second message.

Comment: holy fudge, completely lost myself - I have two open questions on SO and got my wires crossed! sorry - and I know that it works outside the click function - but I need to run it on click :/

Comment: Nope you dont. Do you? I've included a fixed code in my answer

Comment: I did yep, just needed it to run on a button click .. it currently is after WS connection, I think maybe I just need to find an eventHandler to get